# python re.sub() function adding additional character - e - garbage characters

Tags: python

I am using the `re` package in pandas 3 and trying to `re.sub()` a pattern. My code is below

```
import re

test = "xyz/b2117fe1e"
obfuscate_pattern = r'/[^g-z]+[0-9]' 
val1 = re.sub(obfuscate_pattern,'',test)
print(test)
print(val1)
```

The issue I have is that when I run the code I have an additional letter that appears after `xyx`.

The result should be `xyz` for the input `xyz/b2117fe1e`. But, what I am getting is `xyze` (the last `e` is additional) for the same input `xyz/b2117fe1e`.

I am not able to diagnose the issue, what are your suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need [0-9] at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/[^g-z]+[0-9]` is going to match anything (that isn't between `g` and `z`) starting after the `/` and including the *last digit*. In your test case you have a letter *following* that last digit so it remains after you perform your substitution.

If you remove the `[0-9]`, your pattern will remove anything that isn't between a `g` and `z` after the `/`, including any digits (since they aren't `g-z`)